# Break points not behaving with scale_y_continuous()

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I'm trying to plot some data where the y-values are large:

```
p <- seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.1)
cost <- 1/(p^2)^15 * 15 * 0.1
data <- data.frame(x=p, y=cost)
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(shape=18, color="blue")+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Cost", breaks=c(0, 1e5, 1e10, 1e15, 1e20, 1e25, 1e30))
```

When specifying the breakpoints like this, however, all the data points except the first and largest y-value are aligned with the line y=0.

See:
[image: ggplot output]

Suggestions?

Comment: Switch to log10: `scale_y_log10(name="Cost", breaks=c(0, 1e5, 1e10, 1e15, 1e20, 1e25, 1e30))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to rescale your data, such as here with the logarithm. You could just denote this in the labeling of your graph, and still provide un-scaled y-axis labels.

```r
breaks = c(0, 1e5, 1e10, 1e15, 1e20, 1e25, 1e30)

ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=log(y))) + 
  geom_point(shape=18, color="blue")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Cost", 
                     breaks = log(breaks),
                     labels = breaks)
```

Even simpler, a bit rusty:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(shape=18, color="blue")+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Cost",
                     breaks = c(0, 1e5, 1e10, 1e15, 1e20, 1e25, 1e30),
                     trans = "log")
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is this a known thing, that you can't manually scale the axes in ggplot past a certain point?

Comment: Just calling `scale_y_continuous` doesn't scale the axes, your call to `breaks` just specifies where on the current scale they should be set. But that reminded me you can just specify the transformation with the `trans` argument, so a simpler solution than what I originally provided is available.

Comment: Nice!  Simpler solution is definitely cool, but I was wondering basically why my attempt at setting untransformed breaks failed?

Comment: Simply because the graph can't reasonably show `1e30` and the others unscaled. You can see the overlap in text at the bottom left of your graph where all your other breaks are crammed in.